# Jquery datepicker unavaialble dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

**Html**

```
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>


<div id="DesignIdUnavialble" style="display:none;">"17-2-2015","28-2-2015","01-1-1970","24-3-2015","25-2-2015","25-2-2015","26-2-2015","27-2-2015","21-3-2015"</div>
```

**Javascript here**

```
    var unavilabledates = $('#DesignIdUnavialble').html();
    var availableDates = [unavilabledates];
    //console.log(availableDates);

    function available(date) {
      dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) !== -1) {
        return [false, "","Available"];
      } else {
        return [true,"","unAvailable"];
      }
    }

//$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: available,
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
   onSelect: function (date) {
   }
});
```

I'm trying to hide the unaviable dates but i cant able to do it..

when im executing this

```
var availableDates = ["17-2-2015","28-2-2015","01-1-1970","24-3-2015","25-2-2015","25-2-2015","26-2-2015","27-2-2015","21-3-2015"];
```

its working properly.while im using this

```
 var unavilabledates = $('#DesignIdUnavialble').html();
 var availableDates = [unavilabledates];
```

Its not working.. how can i fix this ?

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/2620/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need an array for unavailable script but what you do is putting the whole html-string into an array, so the array contains of just 1 string
try that:

```
 var unavilabledates = $('#DesignIdUnavialble').html();
var availableDates =[];
$(unavilabledates.split(",")).each(function(i, el){console.log(el);availableDates[i] =      el.substring(1, el.length-1)});
```

EDIT: changed code

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
console.log(availableDates)
```

outputs this:

```
[""17-2-2015","28-2-2015","01-1-1970","24-3-2015","2…","25-2-2015","26-2-2015","27-2-2015","21-3-2015""]
```

Clearly its not an array.

This seems to work:

```
console.log(unavilabledates.split(',').map(function(d){return d.replace(/"/g,'')}));
```

Comment: You can split it like @Alexis said and the remove the extra ""